# elisp timedelta output format

Tags: time-date, parse-time

When try to print timedelta as below:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output
(print (time-subtract
    (parse-time-string "2018-10-20 08:50:36.343")
    (parse-time-string "2018-10-20 08:47:43.029")))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: (-7 3 0 0)
```

The output format looks wired:

1. The seconds is negative.
2. Output format not readable, I wish it's "00:02:53.314".

Comment: `parse-time-string` will decode integer seconds, so you'll need to parse fractional seconds separately.

Comment: I think you want to feed those values to `format-time-string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#'time-subtract`'s docstring says "See ‘current-time-string’ for the various forms of a time value." `#'current-time-string` specifies times to be in this format:

> If SPECIFIED-TIME is given, it is a time to format instead of the
>   current time.  The argument should have the form (HIGH LOW . IGNORED).

However, `#'parse-time-string` says this:

> Parse the time-string STRING into (SEC MIN HOUR DAY MON YEAR DOW DST TZ).

So one shouldn't pass this value into `#'time-subtract`. But there is `#'date-to-time`:

```
ELISP> (date-to-time "2018-10-20 08:50:36.343")
(23499 9372)
```

And we can pass these values to `#'time-subtract`:

```
ELISP> (time-subtract (date-to-time "2018-10-20 08:50:36.343") 
                      (date-to-time "2018-10-20 08:47:43.029"))
(0 173)
```

This makes sense; 8:50:36 is exactly 173 seconds after 8:47:43! Cool! Note that this throws away the milliseconds in the timestamps. This is a limitation of how Emacs deals with time.

Now let's get it into the output format you want: `00:02:53.314`. We can use `#'format-time-string` to do so:

```
ELISP> (format-time-string "%H:%M:%S"
                           (time-subtract (date-to-time "2018-10-20 08:50:36.343")
                                          (date-to-time "2018-10-20 08:47:43.029"))
                           t)
"00:02:53"
```

Note that you have to give the third argument `ZONE` to `#'format-time-string`, or it will format it in your local time zone. Passing `t` there formats it in UTC. This is definitely confusing.

Answer (score 0):

That way it seems to produce something reasonable:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output
(print (time-subtract
    (parse-iso8601-time-string "2018-10-20 08:50:36")
    (parse-iso8601-time-string "2018-10-20 08:47:43")))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

: 
: (0 173)